Is it possible to create a perfect pass-through function?
I want to create a function f so that the expression f(x) has always exactly the same semantics as the expression x.
A first naive attempt would be:
template<typename T>
auto f(T&& x) -> decltype(auto)
{
    return x;
}

which works fine when x is an lvalue or an xvalue, but when x is a prvalue it gets transformed into an xvalue, which means it will behave differently in some situations.
In particular,
auto &&z = std::string();

works fine, z is a reference to a life-time extended string object, while
auto &&z = f(std::string());

creates a dangling reference, because f(std::string()) is not a prvalue, so it can't be lifetime-extended.
Other approaches I've tried either have the same problem or create extra temporaries, which of course is not the "same semantics" I'm looking for.
Is there any way to create a function that is a no-op and perfect forwards all value categories?

Subquestions of this would be:


Is it possible to differentiate between prvalues and xvalues in function parameters or will they always call exactly the same overload?


Perfect passthrough of a prvalue would require copy elision of the parameter into the return value... can that ever happen?



Out of curiosity: can you explain the real use case ? In case you cannot implement it via a function, maybe you could achieve what you actually need with a C marco.

"Is it possible to differentiate between prvalues and xvalues in function parameters" Not directly. You could pass decltype of the argument as a template parameter (using a macro to avoid typing the argument twice). "would require copy elision of the parameter into the return value" Even if possible (I'm not sure), it's not guaranteed, so will require the object to be movable.

Use case is to implement a function that does some transformation for certain types while passes other types untouched. So C macros wouldn't work.

@HolyBlackCat A solution involving macros would work for my use-case, but I still wouldn't know how to write the prvalue version, since as you say copy-elision can't be guaranteed, and I don't even think it's one of the "non-mandatory" cases, which means that side effects of move constructors can't be optimized away.

Can you tell more about your usecase? Maybe we'll be able to suggest some alternative.

Not sure what you want with f(std::string()). if you return std::string, you create a temporary, if you return std::string&&, life-time extension is lost, if you return a wrapper, it is no longer a std::string...

@Jarod42 which basically means it's not possible to achieve what I want. I'm looking at adding some functionality to cppfront (herb sutter's experiment for a new syntax), and if you're not familiar with it, it's basically a c++ transpiler that rewrites expressions but knows nothing about the underlying types that come from pure c++. So to implement some functionality, it would be useful to be able to wrap things in something (doesn't need to be a function) that transforms expressions of certain types while leaving others untouched.

@HolyBlackCat I mention a bit of it in my previous comment. I have some ideas of things that could be added to cppfront if we had something that could be used to wrap any expression without changing its semantics in the general case, while changing its type or value if the expression is of a certain type. Because the code that uses this will be machine-generated, the way that f(x) needs to be used can be arbitrarily complex, and it's even possible to for example move the whole of x inside a lambda.

An idea I have is to use a double-constructor wrapper so that f(std::string()) gets essentially rewritten as std::string(std::string(std::string())), which should be fully copy-elided, while other expressions become equivalent to std::string(IntermediateType(std::string())) where IntermediateType can perform any transformation that we need.

No, it is not possible, reusing your example
auto &&z = f(std::string());

if return type is

std::string, a temporary is created (even if it would just be a move construction).
std::string&&, you lose life-time extension
a custom wrapper (with operator string() and so on), it is no longer a string.


I will accept this question because it's clear that it's not possible with a function (or overload set), so it answers the question as is, but I'm still looking for a non-function construct that could do what I want: use it to wrap any arbitrary expression x, so that, for example, if x is optional it returns a prvalue of type T, but in any other case the wrapped expression is semantically equivalent to the original expression in every way.

maybe a possible solution :
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) f(T && x)
{
 if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(std::forward<T>(x))>)
    return T(std::forward<T>(x));
 else return x;
}

int main() {
 
using x1 = decltype(f(std::string()));

//f(std::string()) return a prvalue
static_assert(! std::is_rvalue_reference_v<x1>);
static_assert(! std::is_lvalue_reference_v<x1>);

std::string s1;

using x2 = decltype(f(s1));

// f(s1) return a lvalue
static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<x2>);
static_assert(! std::is_rvalue_reference_v<x2>);

// no problem here, f(std::string()) return a prvalue
auto && xx = f(std::string());

}


this doers not perfectly forward it through otherwise this example would show only a constructor call: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b770dddf8309cce

yes in your example two constructors are called but the last is move constructor  (assumed cheap for movable type); but if RVO was possible ?

C++17 has guaranteed RVO on by default so RVO is not possible otherwise it would have happened.  While moves are "cheap", they still have a cost.  for things like std::string it could be as bad as a copy because of SSO.

At least this solution make impossible the creation of a dangling reference.
